# How to detect changing of commits in git (github)

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have a repo in github. I have allowed some people to commit to it.

How do I detect if one of them accidentally use rebase to change past commits?

I heard about something called git hooks and github hooks. Can they be used?

Or is there a way to protect the past from being changed?

Comment: you can restrict who can push to a given branch, and whether to allow force pushes. if you disable force pushes for a given branch, people will be prevented from pushing a changed history on that branch.

Comment: thanks, very helpful, I found the option.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable "branch protection" in GitHub. One such setting is requiring a PR to get code into a branch. Effectively, this blocks any direct push to this branch.

Disallowing force pushes also prevents rewriting history.

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule